# Does c2dm works on Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-c2dm

I am trying to use Google c2dm for implementing an push notification for Android. I have a registered server, a registered Android emulator device. Every time i send a message from the server to the registered Android emulator, the application server gets the 401 response from Google's server. 
   So i have the question: does c2dm works on Android emulator? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works on android emulator. did you get the registration Id and authentication Id?
check this for https://github.com/tomasmalmsten/c2dm-android-pilot

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Yes, i have the registration Id (used for c2dm to register the device). I also have the authentication id (used by the application server to authenticate himself on c2dm server). But every time when the application server sends a message to the emulator, the result is 401.

Comment: 1. Configure mail account in the Emulator/device with the whitelisted email Id.
2. if it doesn’t work then Signup again for c2dm with your email Id
I hope this would help.

Comment: I done both steps, but i get the same result. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use google virtual device api and not ordinary apis

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works in the emulator but you wont be getting the device id instead it will be filled up as 0000000..... for device id.This behavior would be same for all app only.See that you use google api.